# Carbohydrate intake query

Tags: calories, body-fat, fat, carbohydrate, daily-caloric-intake

I am trying to reduce my body fat percentage. I tried the low carb high protein routine but that made me very dizzy and I wasn't able to concentrate at all. I figured that my body doesn't respond well to low carb intake. I wanted to know how much percentage of my daily caloric intake should come from carbs so that I reduce body fat without getting dizzy. Also Currently, my lunch is the biggest meal of the day constituting to about 50% of my daily carb intake. How should I go about diving my meals so that carb usage by my body is optimal?

Height - 5 feet 9 inches
Weight - 150 lbs

Comment: I would take this question to reddit.com/r/loseit because it's about your personal nutrition and symptoms. Stack Exchange is more for questions of general interest, and questions that are about nutrition and not fitness are off-topic on this specific site.